# Site structure with multiple query strings (.htaccess)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So basically I want to create a site structure which looks like:

```
/panel/optional1/optional2/optional3/optional4/
```

I have tried following:

```
RewriteRule ^panel/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$   index.php?page=panel&e1=$1&e2=$2&e3=$3&e4=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^panel/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=panel&e1=$1&e2=$2&e3=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^panel/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=panel&e1=$1&e2=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^panel/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=panel&e1=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But it doesn't work well.

Comment: `it doesn't work well` doesn't describe you problem. Which URL isn't working for you?

Comment: Well actually it works but it does not look professional at all. Isn't there a better solution for my site structure?

Comment: Sure it can all be combined into 1 rule but that will also not look very pretty to read.

Comment: Hm, could you show me please?

Comment: ok posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok as you asked, try this rule to combine all 4 onto one:

```
RewriteRule ^panel(?:/([^/]*)(?:/([^/]*))?(?:/([^/]*))?(?:/([^/]*))?)?/?$ /index.php?page=panel&e1=$1&e2=$2&e3=$3&e4=$4 [L,QSA]
```